# Var Scope for External Scripts Inclusion

Tags: javascript, scope

I would like to run my Javascript payload only once per page.

I explain the problem: I am appending my own Javascript payload at the end of each external scripts loaded by the browser. And therefore, the main function of my payload runs as many time as there are external scripts (kind of expected).

More info: I am doing all the job inside of the .js files.

My attempt: I tried to declared a global variable `var check` and to implement my main method as follow, but this 'quick fix' did not work:

```
main(function(callback) {
    if (!check) {
        f(callback);
        f1(callback);
        f2(callback);
        check = true;
    }
});
```

Any idea?

Comment: show `main` function declaration

Comment: It is not relevant to show it. The point is that I call my main like the snippet I added in my post and I just want this to run once per page no matter in how many external scripts it is included then I can have whatever inside of the main that won't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by using a global variable, here is the code:

```
var check;

if (typeof(check) == "undefined") {
    check = true;

    main(function(jsonObj) {
        f(jsonObj);
        f1(jsonObj);
        f2(jsonObj);
    });
}
```

The redundant declaration of the `var check` does not affect its value or whatever, hence this works, no many how many external scripts load this code they will all first evaluate the type of check which was set on the first execution of the main and then they will not re-execute the same code.